# I'm trying to make a PHP variable refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

So I'm making a website for a client, and the client has tons of photos from tons of different bands they photographed in the 80s and 90s that they would like to try and sell.

Instead of making a page for each band (theres over 100) like the previous site did, I am trying to make one page that uses Javascript/PHP to change the image directory to that band when the text for that band is clicked.

So far, I am able to use a PHP function to find photos in the slideshow folder, but I have been unable to update this function to search through a sub directory in the slideshow folder. (For example, when 'Metallica' is clicked, I empty #imageGal, and then I would like to append all the new metallica images from the metallica folder to the gallery).

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = '';
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

This PHP code seems to work great.

I get the images using this JQuery code:

```
$('#imageGal').empty();
$.ajax({
    url: "slideshow/getimages.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            $('#imageGal').append('<img src="slideshow/' + json[i] + '">');
        }
    }, failure: function(json){
        alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');   
    }
});
```

When a user clicks on a band (ie Metallica), this code is executed.

```
$('.options').mousedown(function() {
var name = $(this).attr('id');
        //$('#output').html(name);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "slideshow/getimages.php",
            data: {
                imageDir: name
            }, success: function(msg){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            } 
        });
    $('#imageGal').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: "slideshow/getimages.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                $('#imageGal').append('<img src="slideshow/' + json[i] + '">');
            }
        }, failure: function(json){
            alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');   
        }
    }); 
});
```

I am unable to get the $imagesDir variable to change, but if I were to manually enter "Metallica" in $imagesDir = "Metallica" variable, it loads those images perfectly.

Can anyone offer any help/advice? I've been at this for a many hours now. Thanks for anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have `register_globals` on then you need to reference the variable through the global `$_POST` array. `$_POST['imagesDir']` instead of `$imagesDir`.

However I would state in it's current form it would be a very bad idea to simply replace it as someone could attempt to exploit your code to list any directory on the server.

You should append the parent directory to prevent an exploit. Something like this:

**EDIT** you have to `chdir()` to the path before glob will work. I've updated my code below.

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // this is the root of your web directory
    $images = array();

    // and this line ensures that the variable is set and no one can backtrack to some other
    // directory
    if( isset($_POST['imagesDir']) && strpos($_POST['imagesDir'], "..") === false) {
         $imagesDir .= "/" . $_POST['imagesDir'];
         chdir($imagesDir);

         $images = glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    }    
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

Comment: This is really helping!! Thank you for the tip about the exploit!
So I'm getting $imagesDir to read the right path to my file, but my glob function doesn't appear to be working. Any tips? When I echo $imagesDir, I do get the correct path.

Comment: Bug in my code. For glob() to work it needs to be in the right path. use `chdir()` to change to the path then call the `glob()`. I've edited my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an ajax expert but you seem to be posting imageDir.

So your PHP code should be looking for $_POST['imageDir'].

```
<?php
    $imagesDir = $_POST['imageDir'];
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

Does this solve it?